# Structure xaml xamarin

Tags: xamarin

I want to create a structure but it's not coming out the way I want it

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
 <ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:App37"
         x:Class="App37.MainPage">
<StackLayout BackgroundColor="Aqua" VerticalOptions="Fill" HorizontalOptions="Fill">


</StackLayout>

<StackLayout BackgroundColor="Bisque" VerticalOptions="Fill" HorizontalOptions="Fill">


</StackLayout>

<StackLayout BackgroundColor="BlueViolet" VerticalOptions="Fill" HorizontalOptions="Fill">


</StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

My resolve has to stay this way

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fkz6x.png)

Comment: A ContentPage can only have a single child.  So you will need to have some master layout containing all of your child layouts.  And your Layouts need to have some content in them.  You can use BoxView if you just want to have a placeholder

Answer (score 0):

One smart way of doing this structure is through Grid layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" xmlns:local="clr-namespace:XamarinFormDemo" x:Class="XamarinFormDemo.XamarinFormDemoPage">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="Fill" Grid.Row="0" BackgroundColor="Gray" />
        <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="Fill" Grid.Row="1" BackgroundColor="Bisque" />
        <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="Fill" Grid.Row="2" BackgroundColor="BlueViolet" />
    </Grid>
</ContentPage>
```

Answer (score 0):

As Jason pointed out, a ContentPage can have only once child element.  You can have a parent stacklayout to hold the three child stacks e.g

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
     xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
     xmlns:local="clr-namespace:App37"
     x:Class="App37.MainPage">
<StackLayout>

   <StackLayout BackgroundColor="Aqua" VerticalOptions="Fill" HorizontalOptions="Fill">


   </StackLayout>

   <StackLayout BackgroundColor="Bisque" VerticalOptions="Fill" HorizontalOptions="Fill">


   </StackLayout>

   <StackLayout BackgroundColor="BlueViolet" VerticalOptions="Fill" HorizontalOptions="Fill">


   </StackLayout>

</StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```